# The KMDF driver crashes with no useful information from !analyze -v

Tags: windows, windbg, kmdf

I am trying to debug Hello World KMDF driver from MSDN in Virtual Box. Symbols loads and everything looks fine. But when I am trying to debug the code the following happens:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                  Starting New Debugger Session         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

[debug session data]

Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus:
fffff807`0d262390 cc              int     3
```

I don't know what that breakpoint is. Moreover it remains when I am debugging another example driver.

The following message the only message I recieve when I run the driver and hit Break All button regardless of another breakpoints setted or not.

```
kd> g
Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*   You are seeing this message because you pressed either                    *
*       CTRL+C (if you run console kernel debugger) or,                       *
*       CTRL+BREAK (if you run GUI kernel debugger),                          *
*   on your debugger machine's keyboard.                                      *
*                                                                             *
*                   THIS IS NOT A BUG OR A SYSTEM CRASH                       *
*                                                                             *
* If you did not intend to break into the debugger, press the "g" key, then   *
* press the "Enter" key now.  This message might immediately reappear.  If it *
* does, press "g" and "Enter" again.                                          *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************
nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus:
fffff807`0d262390 cc                      int     3
```

And adress of the breakpont is always the same. Also the debugger does not pick up the source code and local variables.

The `!analyze -v` response is hard to interpret because it almost has no specific information:

```
kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Unknown bugcheck code (0)
Unknown bugcheck description
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000
Arg2: 0000000000000000
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 0

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434

DUMP_TYPE:  0

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus+0
fffff807`0d262390 cc                      int     3

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - One or more arguments are invalid

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

CPU_COUNT: 1

CPU_MHZ: e10

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 9e

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,9e,9,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 0'00000000 (cache) 0'00000000 (init)

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x0

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-7FEEGEP

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  05-17-2019 13:39:22.0086

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.17763.132 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff807`0f46db78 fffff807`0d27721e : fffff807`0ce14180 00000000`00000001 ffffd087`89a36080 00000000`0000806c : nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus
fffff807`0f46db80 fffff807`0d2d3c04 : ffffd087`84602020 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000806b fffff807`0d01446f : nt!KdCheckForDebugBreak+0x90e66
fffff807`0f46dbb0 fffff807`0d18bdf4 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000806c fffff807`0ce14180 : nt!KeAccumulateTicks+0x144cd4
fffff807`0f46dc10 fffff807`0d011332 : 00000000`00000000 fffff807`0d074be8 fffff903`28437b80 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x604
fffff807`0f46df30 fffff807`0d1da195 : 000000b9`9e48c277 fffff807`0d077850 fffff807`0d077900 fffff903`28437b80 : hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt+0xf2
fffff807`0f46df60 fffff807`0d25c12a : fffff903`28437b80 fffff807`0d077850 00000000`000000bc fffff807`0d077850 : nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+0xa5
fffff807`0f46dfb0 fffff807`0d25c677 : 00000127`1c58e310 fffff903`28437b80 ffffba01`a64f3c80 ffffd087`00001680 : nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0xfa
fffff903`28437b00 00007ffe`6d921d90 : 00007ffe`63c76dc9 00000000`00000030 00000127`1c58e310 00000127`1cf29fc6 : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x37
0000001b`4ddfda48 00007ffe`63c76dc9 : 00000000`00000030 00000127`1c58e310 00000127`1cf29fc6 00000000`00000086 : ntdll!RtlLeaveCriticalSection
0000001b`4ddfda50 00007ffe`63c75c4a : 00000127`1c58e310 00000000`00000000 00000127`1cf29fc6 00000000`00000001 : StateRepository_Core!dbMallocRawFinish+0xf9
0000001b`4ddfda80 00007ffe`63c74318 : 0000001b`4ddfdc90 00000127`218eaab5 0000001b`4ddfdad0 0000001b`4ddfe500 : StateRepository_Core!sqlite3ExprListAppend+0x10a
0000001b`4ddfdab0 00007ffe`63c73f4f : 00000127`218eaab5 00000000`0000003b 0000001b`4ddfe600 00000127`218eaab5 : StateRepository_Core!yy_reduce+0x138
0000001b`4ddfdb60 00007ffe`63c714d0 : 00000000`0000000b 00000127`1d48d4c0 00000127`17a60000 00000127`1c58e310 : StateRepository_Core!sqlite3RunParser+0x18f
0000001b`4ddfe5a0 00007ffe`63c7fad6 : 00000127`0000000b 00000127`210c9e50 00000127`1d48d4c0 00000127`1c58e310 : StateRepository_Core!sqlite3Prepare+0x140
0000001b`4ddfe8a0 00007ffe`63c77470 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000127`227c5620 00000127`1c58e310 : StateRepository_Core!sqlite3Reprepare+0xa6
0000001b`4ddfe910 00007ffe`5baa75ed : 0000001b`4ddfea40 00000000`00000000 0000001b`4ddfeb30 00000000`00000001 : StateRepository_Core!sqlite3_step+0x1e0
0000001b`4ddfe940 0000001b`4ddfea40 : 00000000`00000000 0000001b`4ddfeb30 00000000`00000001 00000127`227c5620 : appxdeploymentserver+0x1975ed
0000001b`4ddfe948 00000000`00000000 : 0000001b`4ddfeb30 00000000`00000001 00000127`227c5620 00000000`00000000 : 0x0000001b`4ddfea40


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  7624d44a362bc09f63010be40dd2f10b30164688

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  116dd5b296cb899eb0af37455673964c028141de

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  eeaa9c3cd71569b57a2e0c61a2a59028a432624c

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus+0
fffff807`0d262390 cc                      int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  ccccc3cc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus+0

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  438ffec3

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  MANUAL_BREAKIN

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MANUAL_BREAKIN

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MANUAL_BREAKIN

TARGET_TIME:  2019-05-17T10:34:32.000Z

OSBUILD:  17763

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2005-12-02 00:58:59

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  180914-1434

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs5_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  69b

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:manual_breakin

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {30cbeaaa-35e3-de0f-a585-406cd241c851}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

I confused a little by `DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT` line because I build the driver for Windows 10. And also by `IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe`. Looks like something happens in `nt` module. Googling gave no results.

Same things happens with another driver samples I tried to debug.

How can I handle this problem or at least to get more information about it?

Host: Windows 10 x64 build 17134.765, VS Community 2017 build 15.9.11, WDK 10.0.17740.1000

Target: Virtual Box build 6.0.4r128413, Windows 10 x64 build 17763.437

Comment: Thoughts from a non-kernel guy: It's a breakpoint, i.e. an exception. If that goes into your release build, it would cause an exception in the kernel, causing a blue screen. That is a driver fault, because you must not cause exceptions in kernel mode. So yeah, I'd argue the analysis is correct. What would you expect?

Comment: @ThomasWeller thank you for your response! I re-read my question and realized that I explained the situation poorly. I edited it.
The breakpoint at `fffff807`0d262390` isn't mine. It's not on the `bl` breakpoint list. Looks like something bad happening in `nt` module that rises it.